# Split and convert Microsoft PowerPoint presentations on a Linux server

Tags: powerpoint, presentation, openoffice-impress

I have to implement a web service, which takes a Microsoft PowerPoint presentation as an input, and outputs:

- every slide as a standalone ppt file
- text for indexing
- optionally a preview picture

It should also be able to combine ppt files together.

Is openoffice headless can solve this task on a server, or should I go with .NET?

I don't have any .NET experience, so I would like to avoid using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this problem can't be solved easily with OpenOffice. We will use Presentation.NET instead, and outsource this part of the project.